# How to draw circle, semi circle or divide circle into slice shape using flutter google maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-animation, google-maps-flutter

[image]

I'm using google maps flutter and want to draw the circle based on the below values of Area, distance and radius. I have successfuly drawn a circle using the radius but couldn't understand how to manage all the values.

I have tried using polygones but confused how to make them perfect with latlons.

Comment: How will you use the LatLngs with this kind of implementation? Will it be used only for the anchor and the boat points?